# How to stop Thunderbird from checking for new email (is it possible to archive an account?)

Tags: thunderbird, archiving

#### Background

I have an old email account that doesn't exist anymore. Its messages are saved in Thunderbird.

I want to keep that account in Thunderbird. However, because it doesn't exist anymore, I don't want it to sync with the online account anymore.

#### Question

Is it possible to "archive" the email account in Thunderbird, so that it stops checking for emails and trying to sync with the online account?

#### Attempted solutions

My first attempted solution was to go into Account Settings -> Server Settings -> uncheck both "Check for new messages at startup" and "Check for new messages every n minutes".

The problem is that if I click on "Get all new messages", it still tries to get new messages for that account. I then went into Account Settings -> Server Settings -> changed "Server Name" to "imap.nonexistent572.com" and "User Name" to "nothing@nonexistent572.com". That is, I changed these to bogus addresses that don't exist. This seems like a really bad fix, I was wondering whether there's a better solution than creating bogus input. Thunderbird won't allow me to leave these fields empty, hence, so far, I had to fill it with bogus input

Comment: Not a solution but rather then nonexistent572.com, use 127.0.0.1 to save a dns lookup and reaching out over the net.

Comment: See this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1775496

Comment: Archive your mail in a *new* folder under `Local Folders`, as described [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/archived-messages), so it remains accessible from Thunderbird. Keep a backup of the archive somewhere safe. Then simply remove the old account. Unless you need the account for some other reason?

Comment: @djvg thank you for trying to solve this! Unfortunately, I don't think it'd preserve the local folders structure? For example, having the Sent folder and random folders, such as "My important folder". I think it stores all emails in just one folder. Another disadvantage is that when searching for emails one can't use the Search by Account filter anymore (only "Local Folders" instead of per Account, searching then all Local Folders one has)

Comment: @flen Under "Archive options" in the account settings, you can select "Keep existing folder structure of archived messages."

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the old account is a POP account, you can try the following:

- Go to `Account Settings > Server Settings` for the account
- Click on <kbd>Advanced...</kbd> in the "Message Storage" section
- If not already selected, select the "Inbox for a different account" radio button and, if necessary, select a different account's Inbox from the drop-down list (the particular account's Inbox shouldn't matter since there'll be no new mail from the old account)
- Uncheck "Include this server when getting new mail"
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd>

Source: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1292744

Alternatively, messages from an account can be archived as explained at https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/archived-messages rather than keeping around a defunct account. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that such archiving would preserve any existing folder structure from the account.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately, it's an IMAP account, so this doesn't seem to do the trick (there's no such option under "Advanced")

Comment: It might not be possible for IMAP accounts after all https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1262332 , I'd possibly need an addon for that